# WebApp accessible via localhost but not 127.0.0.1

Tags: windows, localhost, jetty

i'm running a webapp on Jetty (Java application server) on my machine (Win7 pro X64) and i'm experiencing some weird problems:

1. when i try to open it on my browser - it's accessible via `localhost` but not `127.0.0.1`
2. when someone else from my local network tries to access the app he can do it via my computer name but not via my local address (192.168.0.14)

NOTE:

1. ping works for localhost and `127.0.0.1`. also, i can access `127.0.0.1` (80) with telnet.
2. windows firewall is off (stopped the service)
3. nothing defined in hosts file
4. cleaning `DNS` and `ARP` chache didn't help

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a looong evening of trying pretty much everything i found the problem - Skype!

after running jetty successfully on 8080 i consulted a friend and he told me about the skype issue. after shutting down skype, jetty runs perfectly on port 80 as well :)

after a quick search i found this - http://www.mydigitallife.info/disable-skype-from-using-opening-and-listening-on-port-80-and-443-on-local-computer/

NOTE: for some reason Jetty isn't throwing an exception like a server should in this situation

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you have only 1 ethernet adapter available, and that this interface complies with the address that your users should type on their browsers.

Comment: Also, from your user's machine, try to do a ping to the Machine's name:

ping MyMachine

and the real ipaddress will be shown.